# Convert TIFF to DTED

Tags: dted

Does anyone know how to convert raster data (TIFF) to DTED format according to specification MIL PRF 89020B and get all files (header information)?

Comment: if you have GDAL, try using [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html), which supports creating Level 0, 1 or 2 cell [DTED](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/dted.html) files

Comment: thanks for your response. my goal is to create the DTED additionals files (DMED, ONC.dir ...). any idea please ?